# expect spawn is not executing

Tags: tcl, expect, spawn

hi i have following expect script named a.exp

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn cat a.txt
```

where a.txt contains the following single line of string text

```
Hello World
```

next i made it executable by using the following command

```
chmod +x a.exp
```

now, i run it as follows

```
./a.exp
```

the output i get is as follows

```
spawn cat a.txt
```

on the other hand if i use the the following script

```
puts [exec cat a.txt]
```

instead of

```
spawn cat a.txt
```

it does print the contents of the a.txt file. plz can you help me to execute it using the spawn? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've not told it to read anything from the spawned program. If I use this version of `a.exp` it gets what I believe to be the correct output:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn cat a.txt
expect "\n";        # Wait for a newline
```

If you're really just wanting to pull in everything that the other program writes out without sending anything in return, you use this last line instead to wait for end-of-file:

```
expect eof
```

Both produce exactly this output when I test:

```
spawn cat a.txt
Hello World
```